# Redux thunk not returning function when using Apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-apollo

I'm using `redux-thunk` for async actions, and all was working as expected until I added an Apollo Client into the mix, and I can't figure out why. The action is being dispatched, but the return function is not being called.

-- Client provider so that I can use the client in the Redux store outside of the components wrapped in `<ApolloProvider>`.

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from "@apollo/client";

class ApolloClientProvider {
  constructor() {
    this.client = new ApolloClient({
      link: createHttpLink({ uri: process.env.gqlEndpoint }),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
  }
}

export default new ApolloClientProvider();
```

-- My store setup

```
const client = ApolloClientProvider.client;

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
};
const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(
  pReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(client))
);
```

-- The action

```
export const fetchMakeCache = (token) => (dispatch, client) => {
  console.log("fetching");
  const query = gql`
    query Source {
      sources {
        UID
        Name
        ActiveRevDestination
      }
      workspaces {
        UID
        Name
        SourceUids
        ActiveRevSource
      }
    }
  `;
  return () => {
    console.log("reached return");
    dispatch(requestMakeCache());

    client
      .query({
        query: query,
        context: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        },
      })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => dispatch(receivedMakeCache(data)))
      .catch((error) => dispatch(failedMakeCache(error)));
  };
};
```

-- The component dispatching the thunk

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../store/actions";

const Fetch = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { getAccessTokenSilently, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    // This will set loading = false immediately
    // The async function below results in loading not being set to false
    // until other components are performing actions that will error
    dispatch(actions.requestMakeCache());
    (async () => {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
        audience: process.env.audience,
      });
      dispatch(actions.fetchMakeCache(await token));
    })();
  }

  return <></>;
};

export default Fetch;
```

When the `Fetch` component loads, the "fetching" console log prints so it's definitely being dispatched. But the "reached return" never gets hit. This exact same code worked as expected when not using the Apollo client. However, I've been able to use the same client successfully in a component. I'm not getting any errors, the return function just isn't being hit.

Most of the questions on here about thunks not running the return function have to do with not dispatching correctly, but I don't think that's the case since this worked pre-Apollo. (Yes, I know that using redux and Apollo together isn't ideal, but this is what I have to do right now)

Comment: Your thunk function should be `(dispatch, getState, client) `

Comment: JFC that's literally all it was. Previously I just had func(dispatch) for the thunk, and it worked fine without getState. Do you know why it's required when I use the Apollo client? I've struggled to find good documentation on this, so if you know of any I'd appreciate a link.

Comment: It's because you use [withExtraArgument](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument) normally thunk calls your function with [dispatch and getState](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation) that means your extra argument is the third argument, not the second.